# How is reputation caclulated?

Tags: support, question, reputation

How is rep calculated on these sites? It seems rather arbitrary -- ie on gamedev I have 2 answers (one a joke answer) and 145 rep; here I have 6 answers (one with 9 upvotes) and 140 rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read that in each faq. For example, here in meta reputation points follow this rules: https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

Comment: thanks! :-) :-)